# Async function and promise execution logic

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I try to figure out how Node.js (v10.14.2) process the following code. Especially why the console log message 'Error thrown' is displayed before 'async 10' ?

```js
const promise = Promise.resolve(10);

const process = async() => {
  let val = await promise;
  console.log('async ' + val);
};

const buggy = async() => {
  throw new Error('Error thrown');
};

process();
buggy().catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To answer the question that is asynchronous behaviour of the JavaScript.

Comment: _"why the console log message 'Error thrown' is displayed before 'async 10'"_ - Not with Firefox, Chrome and (chrome based) Edge (at least not on my machine).

Comment: This behaviour will be different in node js because promises have separate queues in node js see -https://repl.it/repls/VeneratedTriangularLearning

Comment: You can not plan at all the order of all of this. Asynchronous behaviour is not predictible as each thread will process its own work, one can finish before, or the other can.

Comment: I've executed the code on Node v10.14.2

Comment: @Shubh - I thought browsers also had separate queues for promises ... they're called *microtasks* - and the code outputs exactly the same order in nodejs 12.16.1 and 13.9 as it does in browsers ... async 10 followed by error thrown ... OP is using such an old version of node that their result are irrelevant

Comment: @sageagat - use a current version of nodejs, or compare with a 14 month old browser - otherwise your comparisons mean nothing

Comment: @Jaromanda X - you are right. That was a weird behaviour of Node 10. I tried the code on Node 12 and it shows messages in the correct order. Thank you

Comment: Yes@JaromandaX yes you are right  but from v 11 onwards this was introduced ,if the same code is run on v 10 the browsers and node will show different results.

Comment: to be honest, *correct order* is a matter of opinion :p